# Show typeahead popover while user is typing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, swift4

I'm trying to do something like the following:

[image]

As you can see, a popover shows up as you start typing, and updates the results as you type. My question is regarding the UI and how to actually implement it.

How can I show a custom popover when the user starts typing? Is it possible to load a custom view into a popover? Additionally, what would I need to do if I wanted to also include an image view in each typeahead result?

Answer (score 1):

Good question, which most beginners have. Follow my instructions given below.

1. First create a view controller and design it as you wanted it to be and include a Search Controller and implement it's delegate functions in the view controller.swift file(Hope you know to work with delegates for controllers,else just google it...It's pretty easy).
2. Then add a Tableview in center of the view for viewing the results like shown in your question & and add a custom cell into the table view and then setup a custom class file for that cell exactly like how you works with tableview controller.Use just the basics of tableview stuffs.
3. Setup outlets and all for the controls and buttons.
4. Create an array named 'filteredResults' or name it as you like to reload the tableview data whenever the text is changed in search bar.
5. To detect and call your function while user changes text in search bar,You can use didTextChanged delegate function of search bar.

Note though that it's better to find everything else by your own so that you feel confident about yourself when you solve the problem at the end.